Why a pointer can passed as an input-iterator to std::vector<>::insert()
I try to implement a buffer with std::vector<uint8_t>
like this
class Buffer{
  protected:
    void append(const uint8_t* buf, size_t len){
      m_buf.insert(m_buf.end(), buf, buf + len);
    }

  private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_buf;
};

And I see the prototype of the insert() func is(cplusplus)
template <class InputIterator>
void assign (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);

And it's instantiation for uint8_t is
void std::vector<uint8_t>::assign<uint8_t *, void>(uint8_t *__first, uint8_t *__last)
My question is:
Is that said, if a type can satisfy the InputIterator's requirements, then it can be used as the template parameter?
And is this a good practice?

Since you are appending to the end of your vector, I don't think there's a need to use insert(). This is usually used to insert values in intermediate index of your vector. Maybe you should you also take a look at emplace_back() method which also has amortized constant time complexity (when not copying is involved).

Seems you mix assign/insert in the question...

Not sure to understand your question... But indeed "old" template interface doesn't use C++20 constraint, but just naming convention (then also misusage tend to produce compile error, but with error message often more criptic)

Well, yes, the point of templates is that any type which satisfies the requirements, can be passed.    A pointer can meet InputIterator requirements (or, to put it another way, a pointer is conceptually an iterator) so if a templated function accepts an iterator, it can accept a suitable pointer.     Passing inappropriate iterators (e.g. first and last do not reference elements of the same container) or bad pointers (e.g. first and last are not pointers to elements of the same container) gives undefined behaviour - and it is YOUR responsibility to avoid doing that.

Yes and yes (at least it's not obviously bad practice).

@Jarod42 yes, somehow I mix them...So I need to find the constraints in C++ standard？

@cestpasmoi but it seems emplace_back() can't write all len-bytes at a time; if I wanna write a int into a Buffer obj, it has to loop 4 times to write?

@Peter Ok, understood, thanks :D

@john understood

Yes you 'd have to iterate over each memory block your pointer points to. So, nevermind about the complexity. It just makes more sense to me since you only want to append values at the end of your container.
